# Discord bot stopped working randomely, How do I fix?

Tags: python, discord, bots

My bot used to work, but suddenly stopped for no reason and gives the error below.
I am fairly new to coding and mostly use this bot for random jokes. I run this bot threw replit.

Code (without commands):

```
import discord
import time
import os
import random

client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('amongus {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

my_secret = os.environ['RONBOT']
client.run(my_secret)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 80, in <module>
    client.run(my_secret)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 216, in request
...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message. Make sure to copy all the way to the end; the last line should mention `SomeKindOfError: explanation of a thing that went wrong`.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is not setup correctly. What I believe you're trying to do would look like this:

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='your prefix', intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

For the code above including the intents, you can break up and specify which intents you want your bot to have if you don't want to have all of them granted.